# Duplicate key in table error message on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm fairly new to SQL and can't quite figure out why i'm getting this error message, it's probably something simple but hopefully someone can point me in the right direction

I'm trying to create four tables and populate them all with Data. Two of the tables (TeamMembership and TeamSkills) Both have foreign keys that point to the same primary key in 'Support Team'

```
CREATE TABLE Analyst (
    AnalystID VARCHAR(255),
    First_Name VARCHAR(255),
    Last_Name VARCHAR(255),
    Tel_No VARCHAR(255),
    Email_Address VARCHAR(255),
    CONSTRAINT PK_AnalystID PRIMARY KEY
    (AnalystID)
    );
 
INSERT INTO Analyst (AnalystID,First_Name,Last_Name,Tel_No,Email_Address)
VALUES ('DID10000','Jimi','Hendrix','01632 504881','jhendrix@businesscorp.co.uk'),
       ('DID10001','Kurt','Cobain','01632 678231','kcobain@businesscorp.co.uk'),
       ('DID10002','Amy','Winehouse','01632 001992','awinehouse@businesscorp.co.uk'),
       ('DID10003','Janis','Joplin','01632 112642','jjoplin@businesscorp.co.uk'),
       ('DID10004','Jim','Morrison','01632 913912','jmorrison@businesscorp.co.uk'),
       ('DID10005','Brian','Jones','01632 868712','bjones@businesscorp.co.uk'),
       ('DID10006','Freddie','Mercury','01632 963126','fmercury@businesscorp.co.uk'),
       ('DID10007','John','Lennon','01632 990112','jlennon@businesscorp.co.uk');

 

CREATE TABLE SupportTeam (
    SupportTeamName VARCHAR(255),
  
    CONSTRAINT PK_SupportTeamName PRIMARY KEY
    (SupportTeamName)
    );
 
INSERT INTO SupportTeam (SupportTeamName)
VALUES ('Desktop Services'),
       ('Network and Comms'),
       ('Servicedesk'),
       ('O365 Services');
       
CREATE TABLE TeamMembership (
    TeamMember int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    SupportTeamName VARCHAR(255), 
    AnalystID VARCHAR(255),
    CONSTRAINT PK_TeamMember PRIMARY KEY (TeamMember),
    CONSTRAINT FK_SupportTeamName FOREIGN KEY
    (SupportTeamName) REFERENCES SupportTeam (SupportTeamName),
    CONSTRAINT FK_AnalystID FOREIGN KEY
    (AnalystID) REFERENCES Analyst (AnalystID)
    );
 
INSERT INTO TeamMembership (SupportTeamName,AnalystID)
VALUES ('Desktop Services','DID10000'),
       ('Desktop Services','DID10003'),
       ('Desktop Services','DID10007'),
       ('Desktop Services','DID10001'),
       ('Network and Comms','DID10002'),
       ('Network and Comms','DID10004'),
       ('Network and Comms','DID10003'),
       ('Servicedesk','DID10004'),
       ('Servicedesk','DID10005'),
       ('Servicedesk','DID10006'),
       ('O365 Services','DID10002'),
       ('O365 Services','DID10007');
    


CREATE TABLE TeamSkills (
    SkillID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    SupportTeamName VARCHAR(255),
    Skill VARCHAR(255),
    CONSTRAINT PK_SkillID PRIMARY KEY (SkillID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_SupportTeamName FOREIGN KEY
    (SupportTeamName) REFERENCES SupportTeam (SupportTeamName)
    );
    
INSERT INTO TeamSkills (SupportTeamName,Skill)
VALUES ('Desktop Services','Software Install'),
       ('Desktop Services' ,'System Updates'),
       ('Desktop Services', 'Hardware Repair'),
       ('Network and Comms','Network Hardware Installation'),
       ('Network and Comms','Connectivity Issues'),
       ('Network and Comms','VPN Problems'),
       ('Servicedesk','Basic Troubleshooting'),
       ('Servicedesk','Remote Equipment Setup'),
       ('Servicedesk','Provisioning Basic Equipment'),
       ('O365 Services','Mobile Phones'),
       ('O365 Services','Outlook'),
       ('O365 Services','Azure Services');
```

When I run the code, I get an error saying there's a duplicate value in 'Teamskills'. If I swap the code around so that 'TeamMembership' is last, it says the error message is there instead. If I remove either of the foreign keys, the code runs fine, however I need the foreign keys in here so I can link the tables up.

For info, The purpose of the TeamMembership table is to act as a junction between Analyst and Support team.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Please post the complete text of the errors you're seeing.

Comment: From the error you are trying to insert a record that already exists in the table for the Key (look at the full error details and find what the specific key the error is referencing and find that).  You can update your code to do a MERGE or check if it exists before inserting.

Comment: The error I see is Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'FK_SupportTeamName' - which is in fact true  you have it in teammembership and teamskills- you cannot have multiple fks with the same name. https://dbfiddle.uk/at6Mpi6A

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html says:

> The `CONSTRAINT` symbol value, if defined, must be unique in the database. A duplicate symbol results in an error similar to: ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'test.fk1' (errno: 121).

In "SQL-99 Complete, Really", it explains more formally how the SQL standard rules work for [constraint names](https://crate.io/docs/sql-99/en/latest/chapters/20.html#constraint-names):

> ### Constraint Names
>
> A `<Constraint name>` identifies a Constraint or an Assertion. The
> required syntax for a `<Constraint name>` is:
>
> ```
> <Constraint name> ::=
> [ <Schema name>. ] unqualified name
> ```
>
> A `<Constraint name>` is a `<regular identifier>` or a `<delimited identifier>` that is unique (for all Constraints and Assertions) within
> the Schema it belongs to.

MySQL doesn't support qualified constraint names, but it does have the requirement that constraint names are unique within the schema. There is an exception: all PRIMARY KEY constraint names are simply "PRIMARY".